# Use a known map to do navigation

Tags: gazebo, navigation, turtlebot

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi !

Is it possible to use a known map (saved as pgm and yaml) to do localization and navigation in rviz ?

I am actually using the turtlebot on Gazebo simulator. I created a map using gmapping and the keyboard teleop. And I saved this map using the map_server package.
I got two files (one pgm and one yaml). I tried to follow the tutorial about the pr2 (pr2_simulator/Tutorials/UsingCustomMapForSimulation) and adapt it to my case.

When I start rviz I can see my map but the robot is not able to move and the navigation is not working. Furthermore, I can see errors on the fixedFrame /map.

Which parameters should I change ?

Below is my launch script :

```
<launch>   

<!-- start gazebo with boxes -->   
  <param name="/use_sim_time" value="true" />   
  <node name="gazebo" pkg="gazebo" type="gazebo" args="-u $(find turtlebot_gazebo_tutorial)/test.world" respawn="true" output="screen"/>

  <node name="gazebo_gui" pkg="gazebo" type="gui" />

  <include file="$(find turtlebot_gazebo_tutorial)/launch/robot.launch"/>

  <!--- Load map -->   <node name="map_server" pkg="map_server" type="map_server" args="$(find turtlebot_gazebo_tutorial)/map.yaml" respawn="true" />

  <!--- Run AMCL -->   <include file="$(find turtlebot_navigation)/config/amcl_turtlebot.launch" />

  <!--- Run Move Base  -->   <include file="$(find turtlebot_navigation)/config/move_base_turtlebot.launch" />

</launch>
```

Thanks for help.

Update:

The global error is:
"Fixed frame /map doesn't exist."

And in the RobotModel I also have some errors:
"No transform from [base_footprint] to [/map]
No transform from [base_link] to [/map]
No transform from [camera_link] to [/map]
..."
for each frame.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/53972/use-a-known-map-to-do-navigation/) by [CarolineQ](https://answers.ros.org/users/4109/carolineq/) on ROS Answers with karma: 395 on 2013-02-01

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [dornhege](https://answers.ros.org/users/122/dornhege/) on 2013-02-01**:
Please post all errors exactly as they appear using Copy & Paste, if possible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Thanks for help.

I fixed the problem.
Amcl was running but not configured correctly, as dornhege said.
The parameter for scan_topic wasn't set to the correct topic (it was narrow_scan instead of scan). I changed that and now it works.

Thanks.

---

Originally posted by [CarolineQ](https://answers.ros.org/users/4109/carolineq/) with karma: 395 on 2013-02-04

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

For navigation in rviz there is option top menu "2DNavGoal". Click on that and then draw arrow on ur map to set position of goal. If everything is configured properly then robot should move. For map error, look the tf panel on left of rviz to check tf tree. If map is not defined, then using static_tf_publisher publish a tf between map and world.

---

Originally posted by [ayush_dewan](https://answers.ros.org/users/2268/ayush_dewan/) with karma: 1610 on 2013-02-01

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [dornhege](https://answers.ros.org/users/122/dornhege/) on 2013-02-01**:
Also make sure localization is initialized with the "2D Pose Estimate" button.

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Judging from the errors, there is no localization. It seems amcl is either not running at all or not configured or initialized correctly. To verify you can `rosrun tf view_frames`, also check the output of the amcl launch if there are any errors.

---

Originally posted by [dornhege](https://answers.ros.org/users/122/dornhege/) with karma: 31395 on 2013-02-04

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1